# Entity Framework Query - Get distinct region from location

Tags: sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have the following method which is a query helper method which is suppose to find me all regions from a location, there are 155 locations thus 155 regions, how ever, there are only 4 regions, they are used over and over and over again thus making 155 regions.

This code, should do this: `Select Distinct from locations.region in locations` thus only returning me the four regions.

```
    public static IEnumerable<Location> getDistinctLocations()
    {
        using (var db = new Context())
        {
            var locations = (from l in db.Locations
                             select l.region).Distinct();

            return locations.ToList();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I am getting the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Which occurs on:

`return locations.ToList();`

So How do I return a IEnuerable object so that in my view I can loop through the locations gotten back and get the regions out.

Then in the view I need to do:

```
@{
    IEnumerable<UFA.Location.Core.Location> locationDistinct = UFALocationApp.Helpers.QueryHelper.getDistinctLocations();
    foreach (var item in locationDistinct)
    {
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" data-inset="false">
            <h3>@item.region</h3>
            <ul data-role="listview">
                @{
                    IEnumerable<UFA.Location.Core.Location> location  = UFALocationApp.Helpers.QueryHelper.getAllLocationsForARegion(item.region);
                    foreach (var loc in location)
                    {
                        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Details", "Location", new { id = item.id })" rel="external">@loc.name</a></li> 
                    }                  
                 }
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /collapsible -->
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is set to return an IEnumerable of Locations but you are actually returning a list of regions that's why is failing.

Also I would try to use a model something like LocationModel for example (you can adjust the model anyway you want and then pass it to the view):

```
void Main()
{
    public static List<LocationModel> getDistinctLocations()
    {
        using (var db = new Context())
        {
            var locations = db.Locations.Select(x=> new LocationModel{
               Name = x.Name,
               Region = x.Region.Name
            }).toList();

            return locations.Distinct().ToList();
        }
    }

}
public class LocationModel
{
    public virtual string Name{ get; set;}
    public virtual string Region{ get; set;}

}
```